# Merge two formulas into one

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, unique, google-sheets-formula

```
=UNIQUE(IFERROR(FILTER(TO_TEXT({E2:G;H2:J}),TO_TEXT({E2:E;H2:H})<>"")))
```

[image]

```
=IFERROR(UNIQUE(FILTER(P2:R,(text(P2:P,"yyyy/mm/dd")&" "&TEXT(Q2:Q,"hh:mm"))>$A$1,(text(P2:P,"yyyy/mm/dd")&" "&TEXT(Q2:Q,"hh:mm"))<TEXT(($A$1+"24:00"),"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))))
```

[image]

I tried in many ways to join these two formulas, but in all attempts, returned in error, could not deliver the values within the calculation.

I would like to know if it would be possible to merge these two formulas into one ... I need to merge the data that are in the columns `E` `F` `G` & `H` `I` `J` and from that data filter only those that have not started and that will start within 24 hours maximum.

I'll leave the spreadsheet link if it makes it easy to look directly at it the general scenario:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jjLTmfUZUmlAF2j9jXJEKRkAefo922OlMrxhUYBwdP0/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
={UNIQUE(IFERROR(FILTER(TO_TEXT({E2:G;H2:J}),TO_TEXT({E2:E;H2:H})<>""))); 
 IFERROR(UNIQUE(FILTER(UNIQUE(IFERROR(FILTER(TO_TEXT({E2:G;H2:J}),
 TO_TEXT({E2:E;H2:H})<>""))),
 (TEXT(INDEX(UNIQUE(IFERROR(FILTER(TO_TEXT({E2:G;H2:J}),
 TO_TEXT({E2:E;H2:H})<>""))),,1),"yyyy/mm/dd")&" "&
 TEXT(INDEX(UNIQUE(IFERROR(FILTER(TO_TEXT({E2:G;H2:J}),
 TO_TEXT({E2:E;H2:H})<>""))),,2),"hh:mm"))>$A$1,
 (TEXT(INDEX(UNIQUE(IFERROR(FILTER(TO_TEXT({E2:G;H2:J}),
 TO_TEXT({E2:E;H2:H})<>""))),,1),"yyyy/mm/dd")&" "&
 TEXT(INDEX(UNIQUE(IFERROR(FILTER(TO_TEXT({E2:G;H2:J}),
 TO_TEXT({E2:E;H2:H})<>""))),,2),"hh:mm"))<
 TEXT(($A$1+"24:00"),"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))))}
```

[image: 0]

---

or maybe you just want:

```
=IFERROR(UNIQUE(FILTER(UNIQUE(IFERROR(FILTER(TO_TEXT({E2:G;H2:J}),
 TO_TEXT({E2:E;H2:H})<>""))),
 (TEXT(INDEX(UNIQUE(IFERROR(FILTER(TO_TEXT({E2:G;H2:J}),
 TO_TEXT({E2:E;H2:H})<>""))),,1),"yyyy/mm/dd")&" "&
 TEXT(INDEX(UNIQUE(IFERROR(FILTER(TO_TEXT({E2:G;H2:J}),
 TO_TEXT({E2:E;H2:H})<>""))),,2),"hh:mm"))>$A$1,
 (TEXT(INDEX(UNIQUE(IFERROR(FILTER(TO_TEXT({E2:G;H2:J}),
 TO_TEXT({E2:E;H2:H})<>""))),,1),"yyyy/mm/dd")&" "&
 TEXT(INDEX(UNIQUE(IFERROR(FILTER(TO_TEXT({E2:G;H2:J}),
 TO_TEXT({E2:E;H2:H})<>""))),,2),"hh:mm"))<
 TEXT(($A$1+"24:00"),"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"))))
```